# How to update WordPress + Plugins in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There are many wonderful tutorials describing in great detail how to set up a horizontally scaled WordPress install in AWS' Elastic Beanstalk - that part is no problem. But I haven't found any follow-up advice yet on how to manage plugin updates after the initial setup, let alone updating wordpress-core itself. Does anybody know the most optimal way to do this?

This is the methodology I'm using so far, but I'm not sure if it is the best way:

1. Download the plugin's update file and unzip it. Remove and replace the relevant folder in /wp-content/plugins (local git repo)
2. Run the update in the live site like normal - to ensure that any database changes get pushed up to the RDS
3. `eb deploy` from the local repo to commit the file changes and make the update persistent

Is that a sane method? Could anything get corrupted down the line?

For updating wp-core, the tutorials I've read seem overcomplicated - basically rebuild the site from scratch every time an update comes out. Below is what I have been using (used it successfully for WP 5.0.2). Is there any chance of files and databases getting out of sync using this method?

1. Download and unzip the new wordpress version locally
2. Replace wp-admin, wp-includes, and the root files except for wp-config.php (local git repo)
3. Run the update in the live environment, so that any database changes get pushed up to RDS.
4. `eb deploy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been running with the above methods for a while and feel pretty confident that they are sound. I only have a couple of tweaks thus far.

The following assumes an environment where there is one staging server outside of the horizontally scaling live environment. This could be further improved for a multi-developer environment using AWS Code Commit.

For **Plugins**:

1. Run the plugin update normally on the staging server (in wp-admin). Test everything to make sure the update is sound.
2. Remove the plugin's old folder from your local git repo and download the updated folder from the staging server using SFTP.
3. In the local repo, run `git add -A && git commit -m "updated Plugin Name" && eb deploy`
4. Run the same update in Live (in wp-admin). It will only apply to one server, but should guarantee that any database changes get pushed up to the single RDS.
5. Roll out the change to the live environment using the Software Versions page in the AWS Console (in Elastic Beanstalk)

Updating **WP Core** is almost identical except that instead of removing and replacing a single plugin directory, you will need to remove and replace `/wp-admin/`, `/wp-includes/` and all of the files in the root folder *except* for `wp-config.php`

Comment: I feel like Amazon's [official tutorial on this matter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html) is vastly insufficient in answering this question, but anyway… Thank you for spelling all of this out. I wanted to ask for clarification: In your solution, I assume you have `.gitignore`'d both `/wp-content/` (except for its `/plugins/` and `/themes/` subdirectories) and `wp-config.php`? Could you just sync between staging and development (and then to Live) with `git` in that case?

Comment: Also, why not configure Beanstalk to mount the whole `/wp-content/` directory rather than just the `/uploads/` subfolder? That would allow you to update plugins and themes on Live by just doing it through Wordpress rather than moving around and staging files yourself.

Comment: @Carter Pape I'm not sure why, but mounting a common EFS for plugins doesn't seem to work. Logically, it should - but it caused WordPress to freak out in my case. If you get different results I'd love to know how it was accomplished. I didn't gitignore, but just don't include those folders in my local repository. I can't see any reason why you couldn't do it that way though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have made [a separate question](https://serverfault.com/questions/992647/i-want-to-put-wordpress-all-of-it-on-efs-should-i) for this to attract more input. Feel free to add your own answer to the question.